# How can I select all filter item in performance point service dashboard designer?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

I use `SharePoint 2013` and i use `Performance Point Service`.

When I create `Filter` in `dashboard designer` I most select very large number of members.

How can I select all filter item in performance point service dashboard designer in a simple way ?

[image]

For Example : how i can select 48 item in `Select member' windows with a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the dimension hierarchy and select all descendants. Looking at your screenshot, it doesn't look like you have your dates in a hierarchy. I would create that in the dimension to make it easier to manage.

[image]